# Regex: Find newline with no timestamp before

Tags: regex

I try to remove all newline if no timestamp (and maybe a tab) is before

I am able to find all which I don't want to replace, but I need to make some kind of

```
IF NOT timestamp (""|\t) BEFORE \n THEN REMOVE \N
```

What I have develop so far do not fint this line `tt denmark 22:05`

How can i but a NOT before the first Regular expression part?

```
[^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s*]\n{1,}
```

Comment: What regexp flavor are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a negative lookbehind.

Assuming that your timestamps matches `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` then

```
(?<!(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})|\s)\s*\n
```

Should match whitspace and a newline that is not preceeded by a timestamp.

Not all regexp flavors support negative lookbehind, if your flavor does not support this construct I do not think there is an elegant solution.  - The best you can do is to enumerate the possibilities;

```
(\D(\d|\d:\d{2}(:\d{s})?)|[^:](\d{2}(:\d{s})?))\s*\n
```

etc.  Which will very quickly become unreadable.